# sorting lines date-wise and time-wise using python from a .txt file

Tags: python, sorting, text

I've just written a python code to extract data from around 700 text files into one file called out_data.txt

The contents of the out_data.txt file look something like this :

datetime,V_1,V_2,V_3,V_4,V_5,V_6,V_7

2013-03-17 18:01:48.372,100,884,776,009,6553,ffff,987

2013-03-17 18:02:03.828,876,632,887,008,5423,879,443

2013-05-17 20:13:52.488,543,987,233,112,098,344,123

2013-08-17 23:09:08.171,667,9887,9897,09876,0987,098,0987

2013-01-17 35:06:04.172,267,987,6897,9876,1287,3498,2987

.....

there are total 5783374 lines in the out_data.txt file and each line (after the header) begins with the datetime value

However, the problem I have is that the code I wrote extracts the data from each individual file and adds to to my out_data.txt file but the lines are not in the order of date-time as you can see above. 
I was hoping to get my lines to be in date time order because I need to plot this data.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
import re  #regular expressions
import glob #file management and reading

if __name__ == "__main__":   #opening for python
all_header=[]       #list declaration
all_values=[]       #list declaration
i=0
with open('out_data.txt', 'w') as of:    #output file
    for infile in glob.glob("/Users/name/Desktop/raw_data/*.txt"):      #input file
            with open(infile) as fobj:
            print "processing file {}".format(infile)
            for line in fobj:
                data = line.split()   #split each line into individual tokens
                if len(data)==2 and re.search(r'(\d+-\d+-\d+)',    data[0]):    #regular expression to identify date and time
                    header=['datetime']  #column name datetime
                    values=[data[0]+" "+data[1]]  #date+time as one value
                else:
                    header=[d for d in data if data.index(d)%2==0]
                    values=[d for d in data if data.index(d)%2!=0]
                all_header.extend(header)
                all_values.extend(values)
                if not header:
                    if i==0:
                        of.write(','.join(all_header))
                    i=i+1
                    of.write("\n")
                    of.write(','.join(all_values))
                    all_header = []
                    all_values = []
        of.write("\n")
        of.write(','.join(all_values))
```

My expected result from the example data I gave above would be

datetime,V_1,V_2,V_3,V_4,V_5,V_6,V_7

2013-01-17 35:06:04.172,267,987,6897,9876,1287,3498,2987

2013-03-17 18:01:48.372,100,884,776,009,6553,ffff,987

2013-03-17 18:02:03.828,876,632,887,008,5423,879,443

2013-05-17 20:13:52.488,543,987,233,112,098,344,123

2013-08-17 23:09:08.171,667,9887,9897,09876,0987,098,0987

but of course, I couldn't really figure out how to include the sort element in the code or if there is any other way to do that.

Thank you!!

Comment: Actually it doesn't appear to show the format of my out_data.txt file properly:

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas. A simple example would be as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

df_list = []
for infile in glob.glob("/Users/name/Desktop/raw_data/*.txt"):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(infile,parse_dates=['datetime']))
df = pd.concat(df_list).sort_values(by='datetime')
df.to_csv('out_data.txt',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an ordinary (dictionary order) sort with keying on the 1st
field if the date/time is formatted in a fixed length.

Please try the following:

```
import csv

with open("out_data.txt", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    header = next(reader)
    sortedlist = sorted(reader, key = lambda x: x[0])

with open("sorted.txt", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(sortedlist)
```

It will be easy to embed the fragment above in your code.

As an alternative, you can say with `bash`:

```
head -1 out_data.txt > sorted.txt
tail +2 out_data.txt | sort -t, -k1 >> sorted.txt
```

Hope this helps.